# Viewport height 100vh gets tallter at mobiles devices

Tags: html

I'm facing an issue with vh. Im using 100vh to make a div element 100% height, as a fullscreen image. On desktop it works fine, but on mobile devices this div gets much taller than it should be (for example, my mobile has 5'' ratio and resolution 720x1280.
Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and link it to the question?

Comment: Is there a `<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />` in the `<head>`? (or `@viewport {width: device-width;}` in CSS)